# Is Lead.Name 100% predictable?

Tags: apex, leads, asynchronous, einstein-recommendations, name

We have an integration with a third party site which requires an exact match for the Lead Name.
When we have a new lead, we need to make a call out to this website.

In Trigger.new, Lead.Name is always null.
True, I need to create an asynchronous process to make the callout and by the time the async process happens, there will be a completed record I *could* SOQL query to get the name.

But since SOQL queries are limited and I already have Lead.FirstName and Lead.LastName, do I really need to make that query?

Or would it be safe to just use `lead.FirstName + ' ' + lead.LastName`, as I'll already have these values?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation on [`Lead`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) seems pretty clear:

> #### Name
>
> **Description**
> Concatenation of FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix up to 203 characters, including whitespaces.

Comment: Cheers for the fast response.  Can you please give me a link to this documentation?  Also, will they always be in this order and separated by a single space?

Comment: I typed out the markdown syntax but forgot to actually include the link. Done. Pretty sure they will always be space joined in this order, yes.

Comment: Cheers again.... Also, could there be regional variations on that?  I'm working for a German company and so far as I can tell, we don't seem to have the Middle Name or Suffix fields.  Is there any chance some other fields might be used instead?

Comment: I would hope the documentation would indicate it to be locale specific were that the case. I can try to do some testing later.

Comment: any output on that testing?